# Delegating the loading of specific resources (images, etc) to the local filesystem in an Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I'm using a WebView in my Android app to load up our Web App, eg...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _web_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    _web_view.loadUrl(R.strings.url);
}
```

So far, so good.

What I want to do is selectively choose to load available assets out of the local Android filesystem when the WebView requests them. The idea is that I will save significant load time and bandwidth by packaging static image assets into the Android and serving them from the filesystem, rather than requesting them from the web server.

I see that the WebViewClient class has a onLoadResource method. This is very close to what I want, except I would like to have a way to tell the app "no, don't download it from THAT url, use THIS url instead" (and point to the local filesystem).

The best approach I can think of thus far is to simply have a different copy of our .html file that points to the Android filesystem, but I would prefer to selectively replace the assets on the clientside rather than maintaining 2 copies of the HTML on the server...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at overriding [`shouldInterceptRequest`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) instead. It seems to be what you want. The downside being requiring API 11+.

Comment: Nice! Not sure how I missed this; I swear I read the documentation ;)